# Dynamic SQL used in Case Statement in Stored Procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, case, dynamic-sql

I am developing a proof of concept application as requested by a client to act as a automation system that does an initial scrub of input data. One of the steps in this process is to look at a description field and determine how that maps to the clients provided description/code list to get a specific code. I initially thought of just using a giant case statement, however, due to the input data not always being the same, I figured I would incorporate dynamic SQL to pass the column name of the input description field. Below is a snippet of code thus far (the ellipses (...) represent code continuing for an unknown distance at this point and are not truly in the code.):

```
DECLARE @DESC VARCHAR(100)
SET @DESC = '<sourceDescrptionColumn>'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = '
            SELECT 
              <sourceDescrptionColumn>
              ,CASE WHEN( ' + @DESC + ' LIKE ''%club%'') THEN ''00''
                    WHEN( ' + @DESC + ' LIKE ''%ball%''  AND  ' + @DESC + '  NOT LIKE ''%basket%'' AND ' + @DESC + ' NOT LIKE ''%base%'') THEN ''01''
                    WHEN( ' + @DESC + ' LIKE ''%glov%''  AND  ' + @DESC + '  NOT LIKE ''%bat%'' AND ' + @DESC + ' NOT LIKE ''%golf%'' AND ...) THEN ''02''
                    ...
                    ESLE ''99''
                END AS DESC_CODE
            FROM <someInputTable>'
```

This will work for roughly the first 30 or so "WHEN" statements and then it begins to fail. It appears to be an issue with my use of single quotes, but I cannot seem to locate the source.

Are there limits to the number of ANDs or WHENs that can be used in this type of SQL usage? Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Can you expand on "fail"? An error message? Doesn't return correct results? I assume that `ESLE` is just a copy and paste error. And that `@DESC` would never contain any characters that might trip things up.

Comment: There is a batch size limit documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms143432.aspx), but with a default of 64K * 4K it doesn't look like an issue. It might not even be applicable when the database engine is muttering to itself with dynamic SQL.

Comment: So the error I get is a Syntax error, but it changes deepening on the number of WHEN statements in the CASE Statement. For example, when I have 31 WHENs in the statement it'll say something along the lines of "incorrect syntax near "L", when I have 32 WHENs in the statement it'll say something along the lines of "incorrect syntax near "LIK", so on and so forth. As far as I can see, no there are not any odd characters that would cause the issue.

Comment: The reason I am convinced that it is my use of single quotes is that after 47 lines, it will say "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'Current_Invento'." Notice that it is cutting off the word inventory. This is the database name in the FROM section. The FROM should read as [Current_Inventory].[dbo].[Products]

Comment: You should be creating a Unicode string using the "N" prefix, e.g. `SET @SQL = N'SELECT ...'`. Is the length where the error occurs a "magic" number, e.g. 4000, 4096, 8000 or 8192?

Comment: to eliminate the possibility that something is getting cut off, try running : select LEN(@sql) as 'Length', RIGHT(@sql, 100) as 'Last 100 chars' . Do the reported last 100 characters of @sql look correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What could be happening is that your data is being truncated as others have mentioned. Now unless you are using Unicode characters, I'd recommend sticking with only Varchar. Either way, just set all your variables to max and that should fix your truncation errors. And the reason you would think it was your quotes, is because if truncate the end quotes, of course you'll have unclosed quotes!

```
DECLARE @Desc VARCHAR(MAX) = '<sourceDescrptionColumn>';
DECLARE @SQL  VARCHAR(MAX);
```

Comment: What is the advantage to using `VARCHAR` when the documentation for [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) indicates that the statement parameter is a Unicode string?

Comment: The advantage is that it's half the size of NVARCHAR. As far as sp_excutesql using NVARCHAR, well he doesn't mention that in his question. For all we know, he could be just using EXEC(@sql).

Comment: Thank you Stephan, that seems to be the answer!